# How can I change the path I access Nagios with in my browser?

Tags: apache-2.2, nagios

I normally access nagios at mysite.com/nagios3/ but how do I change that?

In the /etc/nagios3/apache2.conf file there are these (and other) variables:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/nagios3 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3
ScriptAlias /nagios3/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3

# Where the stylesheets (config files) reside
Alias /nagios3/stylesheets /etc/nagios3/stylesheets

# Where the HTML pages live
Alias /nagios3 /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs
```

I changed them to this:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/test /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3
ScriptAlias /test/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3

# Where the stylesheets (config files) reside
Alias /test/stylesheets /etc/nagios3/stylesheets

# Where the HTML pages live
Alias /test /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs
```

Then I can access nagios at mysite.com/test - however the images are not loading as they are still being referenced at /nagios3/images/...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/nagios3/cgi.cfg` and set:

```
url_html_path=/test
```